# What does the phrase “fallen off the lips” mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases, expressions

I was listening to a interview in which the following dialogue occurred:

Interviewer: “I went to a church service for years and the words ‘poor’ and ‘poverty’ never crossed the lips of anyone or any sermon”

Interviewee: “Well they might have *fallen off the lips*”

What is meant by the phrase *fallen off the lips*?

Comment: They might have spoken those words. cross someone's lips is an idiom. Here, they mean said inadvertently.

Comment: I got the impression from the overall interview that the interviewee was being critical of the church in particular,  and of religion in general, as if to say the words may have been spoken without any sincerity.

Comment: I'd generally take that to mean that people may have used those words in a casual, unconscious, or off-the-cuff manner, not in the dedicated, thoughtful sense one might expect from Christians in that context. I.e., it's likely the pastor used the words 'poor' or 'poverty' when reading a bible quote or in casual discussion, but never made them the focus of a sermon.

Comment: @TedWrigley You may be onto something there. When I commented that I thought the interviewee was being critical, I meant that he seemed not too impressed with the lack of those words being said, when they should’ve been said sometime during a sermon over the course of a long period of time. So it may very well be as you implied - that the church referred to in the interview doesn’t take the concepts of caring for the poor, and the issue of poverty, seriously enough, or at least as serious as a traditional Christian should.

Comment: @TedWrigley maybe the phrase “paying lip service to ...” is similar.

Comment: “Falling from my lips” appears towards the end of *These Dreams* by the band Heart. It’s a frequently-played classic, so its sense of the phrase is probably in many people’s minds.  https://www.google.com/search?q=these+dreams+lyrics&rlz=1CDGOYI_enCA680US681&oq=these+dreams+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i131i433j0l2j46j0.6112j0j4&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8